# Blazor JS interop: how to pass undefined to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In a blazor project a JavaScript function distinguishes between `null` and `undefined`. When passing `null` from C# (`await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<long>("func", null, "str")`) the JS side receives value `null` (`typeof arg1 === 'object'`). What to pass from C# side to receive `undefined` (`typeof arg1 === 'undefined'`)?

Edit:
Apparently the behavior of `null` is not consistent, it depends on the position of the argument.
JS:

```
        func1: function (arg1) {
            console.log("func1", typeof arg1);
        },
        func2: function (arg1, arg2) {
            console.log("func2", typeof arg1);
        },
```

C#:

```
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("utils.func1", null);
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("utils.func1");
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("utils.func1", "aaa");
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("utils.func2", null, 123);
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("utils.func2", "aaa", 123);
```

Output:

```
func1 undefined
func1 undefined
func1 string
func2 object
func2 string
```

Comment: has you try `await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<long>("func")`?

Comment: No repro. Can you post the JS func() ?  And tell us what version(s) you are using.

Comment: Edited: added an example that reproduces the issue. Of course it's possible to omit the arguments from the end to get `undefined` in JS. My problem was with getting undefined for a middle argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if you send an argument or if null in the javascript function you can use `===undefined` or `===null`.

```
<script>
    var func1=(arg1)=> {
        console.log("func1", arg1,arg1===null,arg1===undefined,typeof arg1);
    }
</script>
```

but you need send "null explicity"

```
    var data = (string)null; //<--I check with this
    await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("func1","Hello world");
    await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("func1", data);
    await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("func1");
```